# Retag 'registrar' and 'domain-registrar'

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Personally I like 'domain-registrar' better but it seems as though 'registrar' gets used much more. Either way I don't think we need both tags.

Also up for discussion:
domain(213)
domains(28)

domain-name(55)
domainname(2)
domain-names(1)

Though I can these being a problem since some I'm sure some are referring to windows domains and some to website domains.

Comment: I'd go change them, but my SF rep is too low.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `domain-registrar` should be used despite the stats (`registrar` ×20, `domain-registrar` ×2), but the majority ones for the others (`domain`, `domain-name`).

Comment: That was my feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really see any ambiguity in the future where we someone would use registrar and not mean a provider of DNS services?  Personally I am a big fan of using the most simple tag whenever possible.

I retagged domainname and domain-names to domain-name since that one is pretty clear.  I also retagged subdomains(3) to subdomain(100) while I was at it.

Comment: I do agree but for the time being every one of the registrar tags that exists is regarding a web domain so retagging now would be appropriate. If at a later date the registrar tag is needed for some other purpose it can be recreated.